# Raster Analysis tools fail

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

When trying to run some raster analysis tools (e.g., the Proximity tool) on my layer, I get the following output:

```
Algorithm 'Proximity (raster distance)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'BAND' : 1, 'DATA_TYPE' : 5, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : 'crs=EPSG:3857&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=PS.ProtectedSite.nlps-st&styles&url=https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/provincies/ps/wms/v1', 'MAX_DISTANCE' : 0, 'NODATA' : 0, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'REPLACE' : 0, 'UNITS' : 1, 'VALUES' : '' }

GDAL command:
gdal_proximity.bat -srcband 1 -distunits PIXEL -nodata 0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff "crs=EPSG:3857&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=PS.ProtectedSite.nlps-st&styles&url=https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/provincies/ps/wms/v1" C:/Users/marti/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_EDtttF/b7930f1096bd43f9bc75eff1964b25e3/OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:

gdal_proximity.py srcfile dstfile [-srcband n] [-dstband n] 
[-of format] [-co name=value]* 
[-ot Byte/UInt16/UInt32/Float32/etc] 
[-values n,n,n] [-distunits PIXEL/GEO] 
[-maxdist n] [-nodata n] [-use_input_nodata YES/NO] 
[-fixed-buf-val n] [-q]
'dpiMode' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
Invalid parameter - /png
'layers' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
'styles' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
'url' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
Process returned error code 1
```

For some reason it seems to think that those `dpiMode` and `layers` settings are separate commands.

I'm using the latest version of QGIS (3.22.1) and am on Windows 10.

Any clue?

Comment: Okay thanks. It's would've been helpful if the editor would provide proper feedback then, but okay. Then the next question would be: how can I use this functionality on WMS data? I'm new to this tool, so any details on how to properly do that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can't do it at all. WMS layers do not store any meaningful data values, they are just a map image rendered as pixels (picture). You can't do any analysis with this. You must use other data sources, e.g. a WCS (Web Coverage Service), see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Coverage_Service